# como filtrar e trazer uma lista de atributos baseado no ano escolhido pelo usuário

Tags: java, sql, spring, jpa, db2

Boa noite, atualmente faço estágio e lá nós utilizamos Java em principal e utilizamos o spring boot para desenvolvimento de páginas web, a dúvida é o seguinte, lá possuo uma Query pronta que faz uma busca no banco de dados com diferentes tabelas e relações, o que ocorre é que a página que estou desenvolvendo, o usuário terá que fazer uma escolha de algum ano em específico e assim traga específicos campos da tabela de acordo com o ano selecionado na página, como uma "List", mas estou tendo dificuldades de formulação do método no controller, se eu fosse utilizar um MVC, como eu poderia estrututar esse código? para que assim eu associe o objeto no html, usamos o JpaRepository para buscas no banco. Consigo obter algum norte? não consigo mostrar a ideia do projeto pois no momento não estou no estágio.

Além da Query já pronta que seleciona TODOS OS CAMPOS independentes do ano nas suas respectivas tabelas, já fiz as estruturas como as entidades, repositório (que contém a Query pronta) e agora preciso finalizar o controller e associar no html.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -2):

public class Exemplo {
private int id;
private String nome;
private int ano;
}

@GetMapping("/exemplos/{ano}")
public List buscarExemplosPorAno(@PathVariable int ano) {
// TODO: implementar lógica para buscar exemplos por ano
}

public List buscarExemplosPorAno(int ano) {
String sql = "SELECT * FROM exemplos WHERE ano = ?";
return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new Object[]{ano}, (rs, rowNum) -> {
Exemplo exemplo = new Exemplo();
exemplo.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
exemplo.setNome(rs.getString("nome"));
exemplo.setAno(rs.getInt("ano"));
return exemplo;
});
}

@GetMapping("/exemplos/{ano}")
public List buscarExemplosPorAno(@PathVariable int ano) {
List exemplos = buscarExemplosPorAno(ano);
return exemplos;
}